# N Layer Message management in .net

Tags: .net, cookies, session-state, tempdata, n-layer

Im developing a .NET N Layer web application.

I need to display a message from something that MIGHT happen in a service layer call.

This message however will not be displayed in the current view but after a redirect. Ive been searching around and im going to implement a cookie temp data provider (because im trying to avoid session state).

However using TEMPDATA cookie provider from the service layer seems kind of a badsmell.

Are there any alternatives to the messaging SL to UI (Redirect)??

Comment: Do you mean [*n-tier*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)?